# unable to set state when setting the value of text field from another screens response

Tags: react-native

I am new to React Native, I am getting "maximum update depth exceeded" error while trying to set state.

In my first screen, i have a textInput and a button to scan QR/Bar code,
clicking on button opens a screen where i scan the QR/Bar code and send back the value and set the value to textInput.

Below is the code of my screens and i have defined my problem in comments.

```
//Screen1 => BarCodeScanning Screen1
// from BarCOdeScanning screen, i am returning the value like this
// which is working fine. the data is present in 
// this.props.navigation.getParam("data).
// (able to fetch data in Second Screen)

handleBarCodeScanned = ({ type, data }) => {
   this.props.navigation.navigate("IssueIMR", { data:data, 
   type:type });
};

//Screen2 => HomeScreen

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
    isLoading: true,
    BarCodeValue : ""
    };
}

render() {
const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
const { navigation } = this.props;

//if i try to set state like below i am getting an error: maximum 
// update depth exceeded
if(navigation.getParam("data")){
    this.setstate({
        BarCodeValue: navigation.getParam("data")
    })
}

// I am able to get and store value of barcode like this. but i 
// want to store the value in state.
var BarCodeValue = navigation.getParam("data");

return (
<View style={styles.container}>
<View style={{ marginTop: 10 }}>

    <View style={CommonStyles.containerOne}>
    <Text style={{ marginRight: 5 }}>Scan Bar Code</Text>
    <TextInput
        placeholder="Bar Code"
        autoCapitalize="none"
        // this onChangeText prop is only working when i am typing 
        // something manually, when i am setting the value in 
        // textfield from the response of screen, this function is 
        // not executing.
        onChangeText={text => {
            BarCodeValue = text;
        }}
        // And one more strange thing is happening...after getting 
        // the value of barcode from BarCodeScreen, when i am 
        // typing 
        // something manually, the value changes to the value i get 
        // after scanning the barcode. for ex, i get the value of 
        // barcode 12345, and set it to textInput, now if i add or 
        // remove  
        // any number to the textInput, it automatically sets to 
        // 12345, which i got from scanning the barcode.
        value={BarCodeValue}
    />
    <TouchableOpacity
        style={styles.button_2}
        onPress={() => navigate("ScanBarCode")}
    >
        <Text style={CommonStyles.buttonText}>Scan</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
</View>
</View>
 );
 }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Never use `setState` inside `render` method. This will cause a loop of re-rendering and state will again change. This is the cause for `maximum update depth exceeded` error.

Remove the below code from your `render` method;

```
const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
const { navigation } = this.props;
if(navigation.getParam("data")){
   this.setState({
       BarCodeValue: navigation.getParam("data")
   })
}

var BarCodeValue = navigation.getParam("data");
```

Move this code to some lifecycle method like `componentDidMount` or `componenetDidUpdate` according your requirement.

Comment: I moved this code into componentDidMount, but it didn't work. when the screen is rendered for very first time, the value of navigation.getParam("data") is consoled as "undefined", and when I scanned the QR code and navigated to HomeScreen , nothing printed in console. (And the navigation is done automatic as the QR code is read.)

Comment: Try using ```static getDerivedStateFromProps()```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you try using static getDerivedStateFromProps(), if that doesn't work try

```
var x = "";
render()
{
   if(x != navigation.getParam("data"))
   {
      this.setState({ BarCodeValue: navigation.getParam("data") })
      x = this.state.BarCodeValue;
    } 
}
```

This will render your screen twice though.

Comment: can you please explain getDerivedStateFromProps() method, I cant find a way to get the value of data from navigation. I tried to use props.getParam("data") method but it throwing an error: props.getParam is not a funciton.